# Improper addressing from recruiters in Germany (software industry)

Tags: professionalism, recruitment, germany

I have now been contacted several times by recruiters in Germany
and their behavior irritates me.

First I need to explain that there are two different modes of
addressing someone in Germany (and I suppose some other countries
have them, too).

The first one is formal and neutral: You call him/her "Herr/Frau
*surname*" which can be translated as "Mr./Mrs. *surname*". "You"
is in German *Sie*. This is used if you do not know the person
personally, if you are making negotiations and it is also a sign
of respect. It helps to maintain professional distance if a deal
busts, if a conflict arises etc.

The second one is more intimate: You call him/her by their first
name and "you" becomes *Du*. It is reserved for people having
a close relationship with you (parents, siblings, your SO) and
people who are in frequent contact with you (colleagues,
acquaintances and leisure contacts).

The recruiters in question now used the second form to contact
me. The first one even continued to address me in the second
form after I answered politely in the first form (hint, hint).
The whole form of the letter was also in a form like we were
long-time chaps and I admit that it felt borderline manipulative
(You know those guys which get chummy very fast and, surprise,
want a small, little favor from you).
All were from recruitment agencies.

I am now a little older (40s), but from the viewpoint of someone
working in Germany:

**Is it now acceptable to be addressed in the intimate
form? I know that the tech industry is more informal, but would
you accept to be addressed in this way in a first contact mail?
If not, do you know why the recruiters are doing this?**

ADDITION: If there is a misunderstanding: I am **not** talking about the interview process inside a firm or recruiters from the firm which are searching candidates, I am talking about recruitment firms like Hayes etc.

Comment: It's become commonplace in some circles. For example, business emails, job descriptions, etc. from startups mostly use the informal form. Also, younger people typically use “Du” for their peers, I have heard it in shops, etc. it's clearly not limited to close friends and relatives. But it seems you have noticed this yourself and this question is halfway between a rant and an opinion polls (“would you accept?”), neither of which are a good fit for this platform.

Comment: @Relaxed: What would have been the correct question?

Comment: Nothing, don't post a message if you don't have a good question, I just don't see anything in there that would be worth reformulating.

Comment: @Relaxed Many questions are asking if x is inapprioate or unprofessional behavior. I simply do not see why it is not a good question, especially after looking up the answer of Traubenfuchs (who is by the way Austrian, not German) and seeing [that in fact not all people are embracing the new behavior](https://editionf.com/Liebe-Recruiter-wir-muessen-reden).

Comment: Is there anything in your profile that suggests you don't like to be addressed like this? Given the number of people that would reject the more formal version, recruiters might just be hedging their bets. (As a bonus, if you put it in your profile, it makes for a VERY easy to way to filter out recruiters that didn't actually read it)

Comment: @ThorstenS. A valid question would be “Is it professional?” after seeing it once or “Should I do it?” Traubenfuchs is just reiterating something you already found out yourself, namely that this is now common and *therefore* acceptable professional practice (and also revealing that this is completely googlable, a separate reason why this is a bad question). The way you originally phrased the question is very telling: “Would you accept […]?” is not about professional customs, it's inviting personal opinions.

Comment: Anecdotally, judging from my own experience, I would say it tells you something about the job they are recruiting for. The more upscale the job the more formally they will address you - _"Wir suchen dich fürs mittlere Management"_ is more common, and probably more acceptable, than _"Willste nich mal Chef sein"_. "Du" would not be, by itself, be a red flag (but being tone-deaf in the way you described would).

Comment: @Relaxed You seem to forget that many people here do not understand German, but are already working or planning to work in Germany. This "Du/Sie" und its rules can be quite confusing, so if those people get addressed differently by recruiters, they might be mystified and they cannot google for an in-culture answer. But if they read the question, the answers and comments indicate that it is not a big deal and there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Relaxed Another thing: I was not aware of this behavior change *despite being German*, so it is not obvious. Googling is also often misleading, if you read the articles a decade ago it was evident that Rails is the future and PHP will die immediately. And as you also see, the "Du" is *not* always shared as acceptable. As answer for your slating: I have currently two times more upvotes than downvotes for 390 views and there are 0 (!) close requests, so your opinion that the question is completely unsalvageable is at least currently not shared.

Comment: @ThorstenS. 4 upvotes for a rant and a little bit of trivia, big deal. But if what you're looking for is a downvote, be my guest.

Comment: @Relaxed: Note that a lot of users upvote such kind of questions. See https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/91895

Answer (score 4):

Whether it's acceptable is up for debate, but it's been widely adopted by companies that want to show a more youthful image. It's not a lack of respect.

There are **lots** of content about this already: https://www.google.at/search?q=recruiter+duzen

Comment: +1 this. Also many companies only use "du" internally, maybe they are so used to it that they didn't thought someone could take offense of it.

Comment: Uh, we are not talking about companies. I am talking about the *recruiter*, so what exactly has his/her behavior to do with the company you are working? I can negotiate with a recruiter in formal tone and being "Duzed" in the company, so what has the one thing to do with the other?

Comment: @ThorstenS. Companies adopt a trend, recruiters notice and follow suit

Comment: @ThorstenS. Job postings by companies and recruiters wasting your time are pretty much the same to me. The same reasons apply as well: They want to look hip, informal and young.

Comment: Sigh. "Hip, informal and young" for a grumpy Statler, that's going to work.

Comment: Perhaps it's not _intended_ as a lack of respect, but that doesn't mean it _isn't_ a lack of respect.

Answer (score 2):

I, myself, prefer when they contact me using "du". If they start writing using the formal variant, I ignore the message because it means that this is the culture of the company and I do not want to work in such a culture.
I suggest you do the same: accept that the company is looking for someone who uses "du" for work colleagues and that you won't feel comfortable with it. So just do not reply.

Comment: Again: what has the recruiters behavior to do with the company?

Comment: @ThorstenS. it reflects on the culture of teh company

Comment: @Neuromancer Why? What has the recruiter from e.g. Hayes to do with the company where they are searching? I seriously doubt that they change their contact behavior to fit the company profile every time, especially if you have the feel that there are mass contact attempts.

Comment: The recruiter is supposed to find a good fit for the company. So imagine they find someone who insists on the formal address and send them to a startup where they would be invited to join a nerf gun fight after the interview. It's not going to fit. If the company is "low" on formalities, then it is better to attract candidates who are fine (preferably happy) with that. Also, even recruiters have a style and if they are good enough probably prefer to work with companies that match their style (and expertise).

Comment: I've had recruiters of both the "Du" and the "Sie" kind contact me on Xing, but I find the "Du" irritating even though I am a young German native speaker in the tech industry, and I address all my colleagues with "Du". Colleagues, who you see face to face almost every day, are just a whole other level of familiarity than some random recruiter shooting out unsolicited emails.

Comment: @skymningen Look at online dating: The dating company has *much* more information available than a recruiter (psychological tests and private information). And still suggested pairs which seem to be perfect see each other and...yuck. Why should the recruiter fare better? If you weed out people by the form of contact you are likely to make errors and worse, it leaves a bad taste if it strikes the wrong note. If you want to find out how a person ticks, the best way is IMO to contact them politely and find out in a personal talk (at least telephone) if it fits.

Comment: @ThorstenS. Online dating is an algorithm usually. Recruiters are humans which are able to react.

Answer (score 1):

As others have done already, and replying to your questions:

- Is it now acceptable to be addressed in the intimate form?

Yes, this is considered acceptable in most places nowadays. Both in firms that recruit and in recruiter firms (Hayes, TalentSearchPeople, etc)

- I know that the tech industry is more informal, but would you accept to be addressed in this way in a first contact mail? If not, do you know why the recruiters are doing this?

Yes, I would. This is just a matter of perception on the way of addressing you. In any case, and from discussions in other sites, I believe it is getting more and more common now to understand the formal way as a disrespectful and/or cold and/or classy manner. So some HHRRs have changed that.

---

If you are unsure about the culture of the company they search a candidate for, my recommendation would be to investigate the firm first on sites like Glassdoor (if you've been given the name or can infer it, that's it). Otherwise ask them -- and if you consider that necessary, state your request on addressing you in the formal manner.